# How to change Android application name in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, deployment, xamarin.android

I am working with Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio For Mac and I have created a very basic Xamarin.Forms application.

I have checked Android and iOS targets. I got 3 projects:

- A common project
- An iOS specific project
- And a Droid specific project.

The Android specific application has a ".Droid" suffix in application name.

So I decided to right click on droid project, and to remove this suffix in "Assembly name" field.

I got an exception where I run the app (at startup). If I change Assembly name again to put the droid suffix, it does not work anymore.

You can try this with a blank project with the latest version of Xamarin.Forms.

I do not understand why?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the assembly name of your application, not the name.

If you want to change the application name in `Xamarin.Forms Android` you have *two options*:

- Go to your `MainActivity` and change the `Label` property:

[image]

- **Or** remove the `Label` of the `MainActivity` and add the name in the `Manifest.xml` via UI or code:

[image]
[image]

---

On iOS you must change it in `Info.plist`.

[image]

Comment: I have only "myappname" in Manifest.xml. i do not understand why i see a ".Droid" suffix under the icon app...

Comment: In fact I have this problem with blank forms app project template. I work with xamarin for mac

Comment: Visual studio for mac

Comment: Please clear old comments so we don't have a lot of text here. Its better for future users. I've updated my answer, please read it.

Comment: Footnote: If you have a splash activity seems you need to change the [Activity(label = "Your new App Name".... as well, hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

Other answer works fine.
But I am adding more details .

Application name is picked from **AndroidManifest.xml** file i.e. `<application android:label=@string/app_name` , which in turn refers to **values>strings.xml** file . Do not hard code app name here. Its good practice separate all strings used in `strings.xml` file.

[image: App name image]

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">App Name</string>
</resources>
```

`Label` property overrides this and sets the app title , apk name to Label value set inside `MainActivity`.

Its preferable to delete Label value from **MainActivity.cs**'s assembly directive `[Activity` (as it overrides this manifest value at debug time) change the value in strings.xml so that its global and consistent.

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2):

**For android**
make the change in android folder, mainactivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "Myappname", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

**Fos iOS**
make the following in change in the info.plist

`Bundle display name` to `Myappname`

Answer (score 1):

```
   //Change the Xamarin Forms Android Application Name

   [Activity(Label = "ApplicationName", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = 
   "@style/splashscreen", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, MainLauncher = true, 
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,ConfigurationChanges = 
    ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | 
   ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]



  //In IOS , we can change the name of Application in info.plist
                 
                 Double click in info.plist , change Application Name
```