# how to change the package name of apk file in xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, apk, package-name

I developed a xamarin.forms cross platform app and I would like to know how I can change the package name of the apk file as of now the apk file name is com.companyname.app5 I would like to change it to com.live.scape.tracker can you please let me know how I can change it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613974/xamarin-forms-change-android-application-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms change Android application name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613974/xamarin-forms-change-android-application-name)

Comment: The link you provided is about how to change Application name not App's package name.