# How to change the App name in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.forms, application-name

I have developed an Xamarin.Forms app and I initially named the project ”modelapp”. Now when releasing the Android app I changed the name of the app in ”MainActivity.cs” file to ”MyBooks”.

But when installing the apk file it is still displaying as ”do you want to install modelapp?” And even when the app is crashing it is displayed as ”modelapp.android is crashing”

Where else do I need to change the app name to ”MyBooks” so it everywhere gets displayed as ”MyBooks”?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms change Android application name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613974/xamarin-forms-change-android-application-name)

Answer (score 4):

**Android**

1 Right click on **Android project** and select **properties** from there select **Android Manifest** and change your **Application name**

[image]

2 Change your **MainActivity** Label Text

[image]

**iOS**

In your iOS project search file **info.plist** and open it with **iOS Manifest Editor** and select **Application** tab and change application name here

[image]

**Note:** You can change your package name and Bundle identifier name as well

Answer (score 0):

Open Info.plist file in iOS directory and change your app name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      ...
      <string>YOUR APP NAME</string>
      ...
   </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: From Review: Please provide more details to the solution you are proposing. Otherwise this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question.

Comment: And in UWP it is Project Properties, Application, Package Manifest, Display name.