# How to change the name of the .apk created using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating an android app using xamarin forms. When I crate APK, its name looks like com.companyname.projectname.apk

I want to have it like XYZ.ABC.projectname.apk

How to do this ??? 
Please help. I am new to Xamarin.

Answer (score 4):

**1st method**

- right click on your android project (not pcl or .net)
- select properties
- go to android manifest
- there is a text box for ***Application name***
- enter your app name

[image]

**2nd method**

Change label name of your main activity
[image]

**3nd method**

Remove the Label of the MainActivity and add the name in the Manifest.xml via Code

[image]

Read this for more
[Xamarin.Forms change Android application name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613974/xamarin-forms-change-android-application-name)

Comment: What about com.companyname ? I want to have it as abc.xyz. instead of com.companyname....

Comment: Do you want to change package name? or app name?

Comment: com.companyname is application package name

Comment: see package name under application name text box. rename it